# Are there any alternatives for flask_socketio start_background_task() function in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, flask-socketio

I'm trying to convert a Flask SocketIO app to FastAPI WS but I cannot find any alternative to this function `sio.start_background_task(some_bg_task)`

There are no similar function in fastapi.WebSocket class

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

FastAPI does not have any alternative to `sio.start_background_task` since it is designed to be asynchronous and utilizes the ASGI protocol. You can leverage Python's `asyncio` library to create background tasks in an asynchronous environment.

```py
async def some_bg_task():
    while True:
        do_something()
        await asyncio.sleep(5)

@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    asyncio.create_task(some_bg_task())
    while True:
        data = await websocket.receive_text()
    await websocket.close()
```